# Вывод текста в определеную строку lua

Tags: lua

У меня вопрос такой. Мне нужно чтобы при запуске программы на lua пользователь вводил текс(к примеру цифру 1) стиралось все лишнее и выводился определенный текст, после этого пользователь мог ввести еще текст ( цифру 2)
Снова стиралось лишнее, но оставался текст который был выведен цифрой 1 и в этой строчке выводился другой текст (после введения цифры 2)
И так далее.
Подскажите как мне ее записать.

Comment: Windows или Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от типа терминала, но для очистки экрана и перемещения курсора есть специальные Управляющие последовательности.

Всё красиво расписано на [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Управляющие_последовательности_ANSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI) .

Для терминалов Виндовс все немного сложнее, но можно глянуть библиотеку Python - Colorama и попробовать реализовать подобное на lua.

Встроенные в некоторые программы терминалы могут не поддерживать управление совсем.

Comment: В терминале в Windows можно управлять курсором только через функции WinAPI.  Но Lua доступа к ним не имеет, т.к. поддерживает очень ограниченный набор Сишных библиотек, conio.h туда не входит (авторы Lua поклоняются богу портируемости, а это к хорошему не приводит)

Comment: всегда можно обернуть в сишный модуль. я смотрел там вроде просто все пишется

Comment: А какой смысл в таком сишном модуле?  Он же не будет портируемым.  В таком случае удобнее просто заложить эти функции в хостовую программу.

Comment: портируемость нужна разработчикам луа, а разработчикам конечного софта она очень часто не нужна. вот например winbox от микротик - похоже написан на портируемом гтк, но есть версия только под виндовс потому что с роутера качается дллка виндовая в которой прописанны возможности роутера. примеров море